# Illegal string offset only when iterated as a set

Tags: php, arrays, slim

I know there are many other questions on this but my case is quite peculiar, my illegal offset only occurs when I iterate it with the others but is fine when I do it on its own.
I am using Slimframework.
My array looks like this:

```
{
    "cart": {
        "cartId": "9c7b7c3e-d4d3-4de1-afa4-f81e63b50906",
        "orderNo": 1,
        "orderType": "Collection",
        "customerName": "",
        "customerTel": "",
        "address": "",
        "items": [
            {
                "itemId": 2,
                "itemName": "Item A",
                "itemPrice": 5.75,
                "qty": 1
            },
            {
                "itemId": 1,
                "itemName": "Item B",
                "itemPrice": 5.25,
                "qty": 1
            },
            {
                "itemId": 4,
                "itemName": "Item C",
                "itemPrice": 9.3,
                "qty": 1
            },
            {
                "itemId": 3,
                "itemName": "Item D",
                "itemPrice": 8.6,
                "qty": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "shopId": 1,
    "discount": 0,
    "total": "28.90",
    "method": "Card"
}
```

When I do this in slimframework:

```
$order = $request->getParsedBody();
$this->response->withJson($order['cart']['items']);
```

It returns the exact same array moreover, if I check what is `$order['cart']['items'][0]['itemPrice']` I get `5.75`.

But when I iterate over it like:

```
foreach($order['cart']['items'] as $item)
        {
            $itemId = $item['itemId'];
            $item = $item['itemName'];
            $itemPrice = $item["itemPrice"];
            $itemQty = $item["qty"];
        }
```

I always get `Illegal string offset 'itemPrice' & 'qty'.`

I have also tried the below and it's not a problem:

```
$itemPrice;
foreach($order['cart']['items'] as $item)
        {
            $itemPrice .= $item["itemPrice"]
        }
$this->response->withJson($itemPrice);
```

I might be missing something really obvious, any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You overwrote your `$item` variable within your loop body.  This typo question is not likely to help future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

You did override your loops `$item` variable with `$item['itemName'];`. From this point on your `$item` variable has no "itemPrice" nor "qty" keys, because it is scalar. You just need to change variable namings.

```
foreach($order['cart']['items'] as $item)
        {
            $itemId = $item['itemId'];
            $item = $item['itemName']; /// <--- ! $item is no longer an item
            $itemPrice = $item["itemPrice"];
            $itemQty = $item["qty"];
        }
```